# Why is my jQuery AJAX firing on any button not just submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

This is my first time trying to use AJAX form submission.  I've got it working BUT the submit fires when I click any button, not just submit.  I intend to eventually wire up the clear button to a form clearing action, but as of now it submits the form instead.

HTML

```
<form id="testForm" role="form" action="" method="">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <label for="testArea" class="sr-only">Enter your text.</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="testArea" rows="15" id="testArea" placeholder="..."></textarea>
    <button name="submitTest" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    <button  class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#testForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url     : "processor.php",
        type    : "post",
        data    : serializedData,
        success : function(data) {
            $('#testForm').html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

I assumed .submit would fire on the form's true submission, that's wrong?

Comment: `<button>` inside a `<form>` will submit the form. you'll need JS to capture the clicks and decide if you should actually do a submit or abort it.

Answer (score 4):

Tie your code to the `button.click` event instead:

```
$("#testForm [name='submitTest']").click(function(event){
```

Incidentally, the "clear" button is probably not necessary. It's just something to be clicked on by accident, followed by quiet swearing. Clear the field automatically when the "submit" button is clicked, instead.

Comment: Thanks - this fixes the immediate problem but seems to break the actual post, it looks like no data is being sent now.  I'm _guessing_ it's because I'm using `var serializedData = $(this).serialize();` and now `$(this)` is specific to the button?

Comment: @Chaz correct, you'll have to replace `this` with a selector that selects the form.

Answer (score 2):

Simply turn your clear button into a reset button:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
```

This not only makes it not submit the form, but it makes it clear the form when clicked.

Comment: Thanks, I would have probably wasted hours looking for some complex solution... Although I think @Blazemonger makes a valid point about even including it afterall...

Comment: That all depends on what the form does. I personally would never use a click event in lieu of a submit event due to loss of being able to submit by pressing enter on the input.